# Python spaCy module: warning involving tensorflow and libcudart

Tags: python, tensorflow, warnings, spacy

I'm just getting started with Python's spaCy NLP library.

I keep getting the following warning and am having trouble finding any info on how to disable it—or at least any working solutions to anyone else who's had the same problem. I've tried using python's built-in `logger` module to reduce warning verbosity for modules like 'spacy' and 'tensorflow', and even just in general, but to no avail. I do not plan on using my GPU or any advanced ML related tools yet, but I'm open to installing those if that ends up getting rid of the warning. Any help appreciated!

```sh
2022-04-27 14:45:45.155994: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2022-04-27 14:45:45.156041: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Comment: Hi @Jackalakalaka, setting `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` will help to disable the logs. 
`import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'`. Thank you!